# which is the best practices to update the one to many table

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have two table.
one table is `USER` and another is `USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES`. a `USER` have many `USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES` about 15 attributes.the `USER` table have 18_000_000 rows and the `USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES` have 100_000_000 rows.
the DDL is like

```
create table USER
(
    ENTRYUUID                  VARCHAR2(36)           not null,
    USERNAME                   VARCHAR2(254)          not null,
    EMAILHASH                  VARCHAR2(128)          not null,
    EXTERNALID                 VARCHAR2(256),
    DISPLAYNAME                VARCHAR2(512),
    GIVENNAME                  VARCHAR2(256),
    ...
}

create table USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES
(
    ATTRIBUTEID      NUMBER                 not null
    ENTRYUUID        VARCHAR2(36)           not null,
    ATTRIBUTENAME    VARCHAR2(64)           not null,
    ATTRIBUTETYPE    VARCHAR2(64),
    ATTRIBUTEVALUE   VARCHAR2(512)          not null,
    CREATETIME       TIMESTAMP(6) default SYSDATE,
    LASTMODIFIEDTIME TIMESTAMP(6) default SYSDATE,
    USERBUCKETID     NUMBER       default 0 not null
)
```

now i want to path update about 200000 users.At first, update the `USER` tables one by one,
about updating `USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES` tables, one way is that update user one by one, delete all MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES and insert new MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES for each user.
anther way is update user one by one ,select all MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES and compare them with input MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES, then update the change MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES.
which way is better? and do you have other sqlapporach?

Comment: Sorry I can not understand your question.  I am guessing that these tables are linked based upon `ENTRYUUID` or is it joined on `ENTRYUUID and ORGANIZATIONID` ?  What are the unique keys?

Comment: @join two table by ENTRYUUID. update users and they are one ORGANIZATION and have same ORGANIZATIONID

Comment: so when you update the `ORGANIZATIONID` on `User` you want to update on `USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES` as well?

Comment: ORGANIZATIONID will never be modified. i get input form LDAP and update into Oracle about user info. the info store both in `User ` and `USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES `

Comment: @ Scary Wombat , i change the discription and remove the `ORGANIZATIONID`.there is a bit confusion